# How is a distance metric used in KNN when $K$ is given?

Tags: classification, k-nearest-neighbour

I am new to non-paramtric methods.
The conditional probability for classification using KNN is gen by:
$$
P(y=c|x,D)=\frac{1}{K}\sum_{n\in N_K(x,D)}I(y_n=c)
$$
where $N_K(x,D)$ is the set such that $K$ points are included to be nearest to the new point.

The 2 parameters required for the KNN is:

1. $K$
2. A distance metric (e.g. Mahalanobis):
   $$
   d(x,\mu)=\sqrt{(x-\mu)^T M(x-\mu)}
   $$

My question is, why is a distance metric required? When all I need is to get the number of points belonging to a class $c$ and divide it by the total number of points nearest as dictated by $K$. I can repeat this for $c\in L$ and there goes my probability distribution for the most probable class.

To get the nearest $K$ points, shouldn't I just simply create a N-dimensional sphere from my new point and increase the radius until $K$ points are enclosed? I will then extract the labels of these points and do the usual KNN

Comment: How will you know which points are nearest without using a distance metric?

Comment: @Sycorax I think that I can scan the nearby points enclosed by a sphere by increasing the radius where the new point is the center of the said sphere?

Comment: Changing the distance metric changes the shape of that sphere, and possibly the number of points inside a radius. For instance, compare Manhattan and Euclidean distances.

Comment: Ohh, the metric makes it possible to have a cube instead of sphere or any other kinds of shape. I finally understand thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the distance metric changes the shape of that sphere enclosing the query point, and possibly the number of points inside a radius. For instance, compare Manhattan and Euclidean distances. The shape of all points in a 2-dimensional space within 1 unit in Manhattan distance is a square, but is a circle for Euclidean distance.